# Strength program

Tags: weightlifting, strength-training, squats, deadlifts, bench-press

I am 29 and been working out for about a decade now and feel like i hit a point where my strength is not developing anymore. My total in squat, deadlift and bench was stuck between 1305 and 1350lbs for few years now and I don't have an idea how I can overcome this breakpoint.
Usually I workout 5 to 6 times a week and I was able to maintain a nice shape over the years but I think for a 6.2, 255lbs frame my total is less than average as I see guys on youtube with my size or even smaller passing me by hundreds of lbs in total.

Can someone recommmed a strength program for me that can help me overcome this issue of mine. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you break through a weightlifting plateau?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3305/how-do-you-break-through-a-weightlifting-plateau)

Comment: I disagree with calling that a duplicate, because the question was asked by a beginner, and the answers are aimed at beginner. However, this question comes from the perspective of someone who has lifted for a decade, so I believe it warrants different answers.

Comment: @toh19 - I think recommending a program would be a bit of a disservice, because we have no indication as to what you've been doing up until this point, and a course of action going forward should be rooted in what you've been doing so far.

Comment: @Alec - I never had a program, all i do was giant sets and mostly using the barbell like for chest i do bench press, incline, decline and dips and I do like 6 sets each with as much weight as i can. That gives me pump.. but at the same time I feel that I am not progressing anymore strength wise. For legs, I do like 10 sets of back squat, 4 or 5 front squat and calves till failure, and another day the same week I do legs extension, curls, machine press.. as usual 10 sets each with 15 reps...
I am not really happy about how i am working out but it worked well for me till now..

Comment: @Alec - I think any program could help me now as I am stuck and it will beneficial for me as it will be a new system that my body is not used to.

Comment: If you're under the impression that any program will do, then I'm not sure what you're looking for in terms of an answer. There's a multitude of programs out there, available with a simple Google search. Personally, I'm a fan of [5-3-1](https://www.t-nation.com/workouts/531-how-to-build-pure-strength) but even that's just personal preference.

Comment: I would say it might be worth your while to find a decent powerlifting gym and train there, possibly hire a coach for a little while. Without seeing your routine, form and training history it's hard to make recommendations, but you might be suffering from a case of big fish / small pond.

Comment: To echo Alec's point, it's all about the program you use. Having a random program is akin to just tossing random edible items in a pot and turning up the heat. Use a program that's proven.

Answer (score 1):

TOH19,

Your question is a bit conflicting. You mention wanting to get stronger but also maintaining a "nice shape". The two goals are not mutually exclusive but if you want to achieve maximal muscular strength you may have to sacrifice some physique goals and the same applies to achieve the extreme end of hypertrophy or physique goals you may have to sacrifice some strength. Of course, there are always outliers but you don't see many powerlifters with ripped abs or bodybuilders benching 2x their body weight.

I don't know exactly what you are looking for and don't have enough details to prescribe an exact program or criticize your program but I'll try to provide you with something that will be beneficial.

### Training for Strength

**Goal: Full Body Strength**

- Train 3 times per week

  - In order to recover properly for muscular
    strength adequate rest is necessary
  - Rest 48 hours between training sessions.

*Prior to a strength phase such as this, it would be recommended to complete 6-12 weeks of an adaptation and hypertrophy.*

## EXERCISES

- SQUAT
- BENCH
- PULL DOWN
- DEADLIFT
- VERTICAL PRESS
- HORIZONAL ROW

### % of 1 REP MAX | SETS | REPETITIONS

*complete for all exercises*

**Full Recover Required Between Sets- Rest a minimum of 3 to 5 minutes between sets**

**Week 1**

**Day 1:**

- 70% of 1RM
- 3 sets
- 8 repetitions

**Day 2:**

- 75% of 1 RM
- 4 sets
- 8 repetitions

**Day 3:**

- 80% of 1RM
- 4 sets
- 8 repetitions

**Week 2**

**Day 1:**

- 80% of 1RM
- 4 sets
- 6 repetitions

**Day 2:**

- 80% of 1RM
- 4 sets
- 6 repetitions

**Day 3:**

- 85% of 1RM
- 3 sets
- 6 repetitions

**Week 3**

**Day 1:**

- 90 % of 1RM
- 4 sets
- 3 repetitions

**Day 2:**

- 90% of 1RM
- 4 sets
- 3 repetitions

**Day 3:**

- 90% of 1RM
- 4 sets
- 3 repetitions